# Find the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} ((9+x)^x-9^x)^x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> Find the limit  $$\lim_{x\to 0} \Big((9+x)^x-9^x\Big)^x$$

I simply cannot solve this limit. L'Hospital rule is useless(if you extract for example $9^x$ and rewrite) and there is nothing to gain if you consider $x$ as $1/n$ in order to somehow use the known limit $(1+1/n)^n \rightarrow e$

Comment: @J.G., you are right, it is not $(1+x/9)^{9/x}$ for $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

> Use the binomial theorem:
>
> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \left((9^x + x \cdot 9^{x-1} \cdot x + \text{terms going to } 0)-9^x \right)^x \tag{1}$$
> $$= \lim_{x \to 0} \left(x \cdot 9^{x-1} \cdot x\right)^x $$
> $$=  \lim_{x \to 0} \left((x^x)^2 \cdot (9^x)^{x-1} \right)$$

$(1)$: All further terms have a power of $x$, which go to
$0$ as $x$ tends to $0$.

Now use the fact that $\lim_{x \to 0} x^x = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

We want $\lim_{x\to 0}9^{x^2}((1+x/9)^x-1)^x=\lim_{x\to 0}(x/3)^{2x}=\lim_{y\to 0}y^{6y}=1$.

Comment: how did you get $x/3$?

Comment: @farruhota $(1+x/9)^x-1\approx x^2/9=(x/3)^2$.

Comment: ok, $(x^2/9+O(x^3))^x \sim (x^2/9)^x(1+O(x))^x \sim (x^2/9)^x$, I see now